# Mockito program is throwing java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, mockito

Below is the stack trace

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:167)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:70)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:95)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1163)
    at com.in28minutes.business.TodoBusinessImplTest_withMock.testWithMock(TodoBusinessImplTest_withMock.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @685cb137
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:200)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:194)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2.run(ReflectUtils.java:57)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:47)
    ... 38 more
```

Below is the code I am trying to run

TodoService.java

```
    package com.in28minutes.data.api;

    import java.util.List;

    public interface TodoService {
    public List<String> retrieveTodos(String user);
    }
```

TodoBusinessImpl.java

```
   import java.util.ArrayList; 
   import java.util.List;

   import com.in28minutes.data.api.TodoService;

    public class TodoBusinessImpl {
    private TodoService todoService;

    public TodoBusinessImpl(TodoService todoService) {
        this.todoService = todoService;
    }
    
    public List<String> retrieveTodosRelatedToSpring(String user){
        List<String> filteredTodos = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> alltodos = todoService.retrieveTodos(user);
        
        for(String todo : alltodos) {
            if(todo.contains("Spring")) {
                filteredTodos.add(todo);
            }
        }
        
        return filteredTodos;
    }
    }
```

TodoBusinessImplTest_withMock.java

```
   package com.in28minutes.business;

   import static org.junit.Assert.*;
   import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
   import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.List;

   import org.junit.Test;
   import com.in28minutes.data.api.TodoService;

   public class TodoBusinessImplTest_withMock {
    
    

    @Test
    public void testWithMock() {
        
        TodoService todoServiceMock = mock(TodoService.class);
        
        List<String> todo = Arrays.asList("Learn Spring MVC", "Learn Spring", "Learn To Code");
        
        when(todoServiceMock.retrieveTodos("Dummy")).thenReturn(todo);
        
        TodoBusinessImpl todoBusinessImpl = new TodoBusinessImpl(todoServiceMock);
        
        List<String> filteredTodos = todoBusinessImpl.retrieveTodosRelatedToSpring("Dummy");
        
        assertEquals(2, filteredTodos.size());
        
    }

   }
```

Comment: The specific error is "_module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module_". You can research [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=module+java.base+does+not+%22opens+java.lang%22+to+unnamed+module+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: It seems that the following code is not wrong in itself. The stack trace suggests that there might be an issue with the Mockito library or the environment setup. Specifically, there is an error related to the accessibility of a protected method in the ClassLoader class, which is preventing the code from running correctly. This error might be caused by a security manager or restrictions in the Java module system. It is recommended to check the version of the Mockito library and the Java environment, and try to run the code in a different environment to see if the issue persists.

Comment: All is working actually, Test passed when i run it in my project. So you need to check your setups

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by mockito. Which version do you use? Note that since the release of Java 9 which started blocking access to such internals of the JVM many libraries had to update. It might therefore be imperative to use a current version of Mockito.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I tried using latest Mockito version (5.2.0) and it resolved the issue.